# dynamic SQL query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @text as varchar(100)
declare @rep as varchar
declare @ac as varchar
declare @sub as varchar(4)
declare @stmt as varchar(50)

set @text='1214324324234324'

set @ac='2'

set @rep ='4' 

set @sub='@rep'

set @stmt = 'Select Replace('''+@text+''','''+@ac+''','+@sub+')'

print @stmt
--dynamic query execution
exec(@stmt)
```

I am facing below issue.

> Select Replace('1214324324234324','2',@rep) Msg 137, Level 15, State
>   2, Line 1 Must declare the scalar variable "@rep"

Answer (score 1):

Your error is pretty clear.

```
set @rep ='4'
set @sub='@rep'
```

You set a value to `@rep` and use another variable (`@sub`) to point at the previous assigned variable `@rep`. In fact, your dynamic SQL statement is combined like this:

```
set @stmt = 'Select Replace('''+@text+''','''+@ac+''','+@sub+')'
```

This will interpreted like this: `SELECT REPLACE('1214324324234324','2',@rep)`

Your dynamic doesn't know that there is a variable `@rep`. You need to concat `@rep` into your dynamic SQL instead of those additional assignment to `@sub`.

You can use this:

```
set @stmt = 'Select Replace('''+@text+''','''+@ac+''','+@rep+')'
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to run the entire statement at once. If you run one line at a time, SQL will forget the variables you previously declared. I took all of your SQL and ran it, and it worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: No that's not the reason

Comment: You're right... When I answered the question, the exec statement was in a comment, and I missed it. Everything else ran fine for me, so I figured they were running this one line at a time. Stupid mistake on my part!